# Pass an IP in YQL query

Tags: syntax, ip, yql

Is there a way to pass an ip in a YQL query statement?
The page im querying returns data based on the ip that is querying the page(date/timezone), so I'm getting data that is useless to the user that is not from the user IP. 
What's the proper syntax to passing an IP if it is possible?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use IP address instead of url, here is example:

```
SELECT * FROM html WHERE url = "93.184.216.34"
```

Sample curl command querying Google IP:

```
$ curl -G --data-urlencode 'q=SELECT * FROM html WHERE url = "216.58.210.14" AND xpath="//input"' http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql
```